# Is the minimal degree of a basis of a kernel of a polynomial matrix bounded by the matrix degree?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials

Let $M \in k[x]^{m \times n}$ be a polynomial matrix whose entries have degrees bounded by $d$. Let $K = \{ \lambda \in k[x]^n \mid M \cdot \lambda = 0\}$ denote the kernel of $M$.

> Is it true that there is a basis of $K$ over $k[x]$ with basis vectors whose degree (maximum of degrees of the entries) is bounded by a constant (independent of $m$ and $n$) multiple of $d$?

I was not able to come up with counter-examples and so I guess that it is true. For instance, if $M = \begin{pmatrix} p &  q \end{pmatrix}$, then $(q, -p)^T \in K$ and thus the generating element of the kernel must have degree bounded by $\max\{\deg p , \deg q\} = d$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. For example, consider the $(n - 1) \times n$ matrix
$$
M = 
\pmatrix{x & -1\\ & x&-1 \\ && \ddots & \ddots \\ &&& x & -1}.
$$
The entries of $M$ have degree at most $1$. However, the kernel of $M$ is the span of the vector $(1,x,\dots,x^n)$. So, any basis of $M$ will have a vector with a degree-$n$ component.

Comment: +1 Thank you, that is a very nice counter-example!